# How can I update two tables after inserting a row in another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

On my server, after insert on one table, I want to update two other tables. How can I do this using trigger?

Table one has two columns tab2id, tab3id.

After insert on tab1, I want to update the row in tab2 with tab2id and the row in tab3 with tab3id.

Comment: Add some more meaning to your question, give table structure, Give example you tried.. expected output

Comment: At least post schemas for all three tables and explain what exactly should be updated.

Comment: You should have one value for something in your entire database, there shouldn't be anywhere where your data is repeated. This is bad design.

What are you using to update your database?

Comment: @dayuloli After insert on tab1, i want to update the row in tab2 with tab2id and the row in tab3 with tab3id.

Comment: @user2798694 Then can you not just write that in your MySQL query?

Comment: @user2798694 What column(s) should be updated in tab2 and tab3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hard to tell what exactly you want to update in tables `tab2` and `tab3` since you didn't elaborate on this in your question, but your trigger might look something like

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_tab1
AFTER INSERT ON tab1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE tab2
     SET value2 = value2 + 1
   WHERE tab2id = NEW.tab2id;

  UPDATE tab3
     SET value3 = value3 + 1
   WHERE tab3id = NEW.tab3id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/910e3/2)** demo

Comment: you sir are a genius, all i was missing is the begin ... and. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can INSERT and do an UPDATE at the same time using 1 SQL statement. You need to separate the executions by creating individual SQL statements. If this information is not enough, check this out. It should answer your problem completely.

[ACCESS/SQL: How to INSERT INTO/UPDATE at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667743/access-sql-how-to-insert-into-update-at-the-same-time)